# SQL column=ALL(query): Equivalent meaning

Tags: where

I know that the expression:

```
WHERE column <> ALL(subquery)
```

could have been written as:

```
WHERE column NOT IN(subquery)
```

What would be the equivalent for

```
WHERE column = ALL(subquery)
```

I don’t think there would be any differences between dialects of SQL which support the `ALL` operator.

Comment: I have never seen `=` used with `ALL` - only together with a "non-equality" operator, e.g. `> ALL (...)` or `< ALL (...)`

Answer (score 5):

If not mistaken you can use a not exists predicate and negate the operator for ALL in the subquery. Something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM T
WHERE T.x = ALL ( select y from U )
```

corresponds to

```
SELECT ...
FROM T
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from U
                   WHERE NOT T.x = U.y )
```

I.e.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from U
                   WHERE T.x <> U.y )
```

In other words, for the predicate `= ALL` to hold there must `NOT EXISTS` a tuple that does satisfy NOT =

Note that this might not hold if nulls are taken into consideration. Example:

```
with t (n) as ( values (1),(1),(2) ) 
select * from t as t1 
where not exists (select n from t as t2 where t1.n <> t2.n )
```

and:

```
with t (n) as ( values (1),(1),(2) ) 
select * from t where n = all (select n from t)
```

Both return 0 rows. However:

```
with t (n) as ( values (1),(1),(2),(null) ) 
select * from t where n = all (select n from t)
```

return 0 rows whereas:

```
with t (n) as ( values (1),(1),(2),(null) ) 
select * from t as t1 where not exists (select n from t as t2 where t1.n <> t2.n )
```

return 1 row.

Three-valid logic makes things a whole lot more complicated, and one needs to be even more careful than usual when doing query rewrites.

FWIW, there is an really interesting project that applies Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT) to pseudo SQL:

http://cosette.cs.washington.edu/

The idea is to be able to prove whether two queries are equvalent, and if not provide an example of situations where they are not. Any vendor that adopts this to there dialect of SQL will have an killer app for sure.

Answer (score -5):

```
WHERE column = ALL(subquery)
```

It's a relatively useless construct, which is why it's a good question and seldom seen. Equivalence is a property. There is no reason it has to make sense, and sometimes it doesn't. For instance.

```
SELECT '{-0,+0}'::float[];
 float8 
--------
 {-0,0}
(1 row)
```

That's [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) being stored in two different ways. Yet IEEE 754, specifies they must compare to 0.

```
-- returns true.
SELECT 0::float = ALL('{-0,+0}'::float[]);
```

Most databases *strive* to never make two distinct things return true for an equality test, as it increase the chances for collision. But, `ALL` doesn't just work with `=`, for instance this is also totally valid,

```
SELECT 'fooBar' ILIKE ALL(ARRAY['%bar', 'foo%']);
```